# Proof by Induction and combination:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

According to Binomial Theorem
$$ (x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(^{n}_k) x^ky^{n-k} $$
The result is true for n=1, since
$$ (x+y)^1=(^{1}_0)y^{1}+(^{1}_1)x $$
Let the result be true for n=m, that is
$$ (x+y)^m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^ky^{m-k} $$
we need to prove that the result is also true for n=m+1, that is
$$ (x+y)^{m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}(^{m+1}_k) x^ky^{{m+1}-k} $$
By assumption
$$ (x+y)^m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^ky^{m-k} $$
multiplying both sides by x+y
$$ (x+y)^{m+1}=(x+y)\sum_{k=0}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^ky^{m-k} $$
$$ =\sum_{k=0}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^ky^{m+1-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^{k+1}y^{m-k} $$
$$ =(^{m}_0) y^{m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{m}(^{m}_k) x^{k}y^{m+1-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(^{m}_k) x^{k+1}y^{m-k}+(^{m}_m) x^{k+1} $$
$$ =(^{m}_0) y^{m+1}+[(^{m}_1)+(^{m}_0)]xy^m+[(^{m}_2)+(^{m}_1)]x^2y^{m-1}+...+[(^{m}_m)+(^{m}_{m-1})]x^my+(^{m}_m) x^{k+1} $$
$$ =(^{m+1}_0) y^{m+1}+[(^{m+1}_1)]xy^m+[(^{m+1}_2)]x^2y^{m-1}+...+[(^{m+1}_m)]x^my+(^{m+1}_{m+1}) x^{m+1}y $$
$$ =\sum_{k=0}^{n}(^{m+1}_k) x^ky^{m+1-k} $$

Hence the result is also true for n=k+1.

The following results were used in the proof:
$$ (^{m}_0)= (^{m+1}_0), (^{m}_m)= (^{m+1}_{m+1}), (^{m}_r)+(^{m}_{r-1})=(^{m+1}_r)$$

I've been working through proof by induction and I'm stuck on this question. Can somebody provide some help to prove it by applying the proof above?

Prove: $$ 2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(^{n-1}_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(^{n-1}_{k-1})\text{ for } n> 0$$

I don't know how to prove it using the guide above.....

Comment: See also your [deleted post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402903/prove-sum-k-0n-binomn-1k-2n-1) and the comment there, for the induction proof.

Comment: Consider binomial expansion of $(1+1)^{n-1}$

Comment: And you must change $n\geq 0$ to $n > 0$, because in case $n=0$, $2^{n-1}=1/2$ and sum is 0 (upper index is less than lower).

Comment: Thank you for correction @IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: You can get $\binom n k$ from either `\binom {n}{k}` or `{n \choose k}`. The inductive proof you give is a proof of the Binomial theorem itself, not of the result $2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}$, which as has been said twice now follows immediately from applying the binomial theorem to $(1 + 1)^{n-1}$. If you want to prove it directly, simply replace $x$ and $y$ by $1$ everywhere in the proof, and replace the original $n$ by $n-1$ everywhere.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the desired result is not a theorem, but the proper definition of $n\choose k$. Those who disagree should not call them *binomial coefficients*. :)

Answer (score 2):

expand $
(1+1)^{n-1}$

using the binomial formula . The result is immediate , you don't need induction .